# How can I exclude search results written in Russian?

Tags: google-search

My region is set to Ukraine and Google Search results include pages written in Russian, sometimes even when my request is in English. Is there a way to filter the results to exclude results written in Russian?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPD (11/2023):** An extension for Chrome and Firefox became available - ["Лагідна Українізація"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/eipobogihmlkhppcgkcgcocccpcjcegj?hl=uk), that solves the problem easily.
P.S. I'm not affiliated with the develover.

---

**UPD (01/2023):** Another great tool that I recently found for this purpose is [SpyBuster](https://spybuster.app/). They have a Chrome extension to help filter out traffic coming from and to russia.
P.S. I'm not affiliated with the developers.

---

**UPD (06/2022):** All of the methods below started working again for me

---

<strike>**UPD (01/2022):** Just found out that Google no longer accounts for `-` (minus) in `lr` and `cr` parameters. Only the third option with `uBlacklist` extension works now</strike>

---

I'm also from Ukraine, and I tried to tackle this problem in a few ways, so I just want to add a more detailed answer.

There are a few options:

### 1. `lr=-lang_ru` in search URL (as suggested by [Alex](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/150378/288643))

Example: [https://www.google.com/search?q=новости+россии&lr=-lang_ru](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8&lr=-lang_ru)

Check out [Alex's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/150378/288643) to understand how to make it work in the browser.

This option answers the question but doesn't quite work for me in my day-to-day googling tasks.

### 2. `cr=-countryRU` in search URL

Example: [https://www.google.com/search?q=новости+россии&cr=-countryRU](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8&cr=-countryRU)

So say, I'm traveling to mountains in Georgia, and I want to see reviews from locals in the language I can understand, but with less influence from Russia. Or I'm googling international news regarding our region, and I like `dw.com` content.

This method works better for such cases and will filter out results coming from Russia but won't filter results in the Russian language.

### 3. Use [uBlacklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublacklist/pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe) extension to filter unwanted sites

This extension may help filter out specific URLs or sites by a URL pattern. For instance, `*://*.ru/*` will filter out all `.ru` websites.

It is also helpful in other cases not relevant to the question, and you can block specific websites right from Google Search.

## Day-to-day method that works for me

1. Use option #2 as the primary method
2. Google in Ukrainian when you expect Ukrainian results and google in Russian for results in Russian with less influence on the topic coming from Russia.
3. Use uBlacklist from option #3 to filter out specific Russian international websites (e.g. `rt.com`).
4. When you actually need results from Russia, open up a search in an incognito tab.

This way works perfectly for me, and it also teaches Google what the relevant results are, so it gets better and better.

The only thing I left to figure out is how to filter videos and media shown on the respective sections and coming from popular media aggregators like YouTube.